# How do I generate a .exe C# file in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to create a new project. Then I chose `Other Languages/Visual C#: Console App (.NET Core)` and press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

In the .csproj file created, there is a line: `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`. But then, when I press <kbd>F7</kbd> - the output shows this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApp3, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>ConsoleApp3 -> C:\Users\*MyUserName*\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\ConsoleApp3.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So, it created a .dll file. But how do I get the .exe file? Just renaming .dll file doesn't work; it doesn't open then.

Comment: Select .NET Framework (4.x) instead of .NET Core.

Comment: 1) Do you need .NET Core? 2) Why is the .dll insufficient?

Comment: @HenkHolterman where is it?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb i need an .exe file made in C#, that i can execute on another computer.

Comment: ... on another computer _that has .NET <some_edition> installed_.

Comment: You will find your options under File|NewProject

Comment: @SunSerega - Just because it's an exe doesn't mean that it will run on another computer. Your user will need to have an appropriate version of the framework installed. Same is true for .NET Core (as in your user will need Core installed). There should not be a problem running a Core dll on a system that has Core installed. If you simply do not need to have a Core app, then just build for Framework 4.X (or whatever version suits you) as Henk has said.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb yeah, obviously. I already ran a PABC.Net app on that computer. But i can't run C# program even on my computer (without vs, from folder), because it is not .exe .

Answer (score -2):

If you want just want to have `.exe` instead of `.dll` after building (note, that you need a main function as the library itself without some sort of main cannot be executed) do as follows:

1. Open the solution
2. Right-click on project you want to compile into exe -> Properties
3. Configuration Properties -> General
4. In Project Defaults change Configuration Type to Application(.exe)

Comment: There  is no `General` in `Configuration Properties` for me. Only `Configuration`.